Using javascript cache mode vs cache-control header
What is the difference between using a cache-control header and the cache readonly property of the Request interface?
fetch('/foo', {
  headers: {
    'cache-control': 'no-store'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))

fetch('/foo', {
  cache: 'no-store'
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))


Those are response headers sent by the server, not request headers sent in fetch().

Can you elaborate on this a bit more? I chose the no-store cache-control directive here on purpose since it can be used in both requests and responses.

You can try reading RFC 9111

HTTP caching is a complex subject.

In requests, I think this header is mainly intended for intermediate caching proxies, to keep them from returning stale data. In responses, it tells the client and caching proxies how long they can keep data before it becomes stale.

The mdn docs state the cache mode controls how the request will interact with the http cache only. So it sounds like on the way down to the server, the http cache may check this and the request gets sent back up and never hits the origin server. However if the { headers: { 'cache-control': 'no-store'}} is used, then it could also control caching on a cdn. The above example seems a bit too simple actually.

The cache option controls the browser's cache. The cache-control header is sent over the network and controls proxies.
